# Loopback 4 authentication with firebase login

Tags: loopback4

I have a frontend app with a firebase login that communicates with the loopback 4 server. Now I am trying to secure loopback 4 endpoints using authentication. I have seen a loopback 4 jwt authentication example but I don't have the password in my app as I am using Gmail login.

Now how to achieve loopback authentication in such a scenario.

Comment: Are you using Google ("Gmail") SSO or Firebase Authentication? These are 2 different authentication systems.

Comment: Firebase authentication

Answer (score 0):

We have the same setup: you need to include the firebase/auth package in your application. Then, in your app, you can verify the token passed from firebase.

**UPDATED October 2021**

I have a sample project that shows step by step Firebase Authentication Integration at my Github (https://github.com/alfonsojohan/loopback4-firebase).

The step by step explanation for that project is here:

https://dev.to/alfonsojohan/loopback-4-jwt-authentication-with-firebase-1o4